# Regex with groups on delimiter-separated input with group that is optional or can include the delimiter

Tags: regex

I need help writing a regex with grouping to match the following six input strings:

1. N.A
2. N.A.S
3. N.C.A
4. N.C.A.S
5. N.CX.CY.A
6. N.CX.CY.A.S

The pattern in English is:

(letters) followed by (nothing or letters or letters dot letters) followed by (letters) folowed by (nothing or dot letters)

The result of the regex should be four groups. Given the above examples:

```
Group 1 is "N" in all cases
Group 2 is empty in case 1-2, "C" for case 3-4, and "CX.CY" for case 5-6
Group 3 is "A" in all cases
Group 4 is "S" in cases 2,4,6 and emtpy in cases 1,3,5
```

I have played regex whack-a-mole on this and I can get it about half right but when I try to update it for the other cases I end up breaking the ones that used to work.

A solution would be awesome, but hints or tips are equally appreciated.

*Update 2012 March 12*

As has been pointed out, inputs 2 & 3 look the same (per the English description) and 4 & 5 look the same.

Clarification:

In the real-world input, placeholder 'S' has a known value, which is the literal string 'Value'. In trying to generalize the problem I made it impossible to solve. The updated English description is:

(letters) followed by (nothing or letters or letters dot letters) followed by (letters) folowed by (nothing or ".Value")

I am attempting to adapt the suggestions below. I had not considered the use of 'lookaround', so thanks to everyone who suggested that technique in their examples.

Comment: what language are you using? what is the purpose of this (why simple string manipulation is not sufficient and you want to use 1 regex instead)?

Comment: What is the difference between input strings 2 and 3? Why is the Group 4 noted as S in case 2 (N.C.A) where as empty in case 3 (N.A.S)

Comment: as i understand it, the 2nd group is everything between `N` and `A`, while the 4th is everything after `A`

Comment: @Phani - Great observation. In an effort to 'generalize' the problem I accidentally made it unsolvable. In the specific case of my input, the value 'S' is a known string, literally "Value".

Comment: @deathApril - The language is C#. The reason for regex is that the system takes input from multiple vendors and each vendor has a naming convention. The end-user is responsible for breaking down the input strings using a regex, and one of the configuration pages (asp.net MVC) allows them to enter the regex. You are correct, group 2 is everything between N and A and group 4 is anything after the A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating your "pattern in English" to regex syntax, this is the best I got:

```
^(\w+)(?:\.(\w+(?:\.\w+)?))?\.(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?$
```

Explanation:

```
(\w+)          letters
(?:\.(
   \w+         letters or
   (?:\.\w+)?  letters dot letters or
))?            nothing

\.(\w+)        letters
(?:\.
   (\w+)       letters or
)?             nothing
```

It works for cases 1,3,5,6, but for 2,4 the capturing groups are wrong (tested in [rubular](http://rubular.com/)):

```
N.A.S   --> ("N", "A", "S", "")
N.C.A.S --> ("N", "C.A", "S", "")
```

Making the first non-capturing group non-greedy fixes the case 2,4 but breaks cases 3,5:

```
^(\w+)(?:\.(\w+(?:\.\w+)??))??\.(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?$

N.C.A     --> ("N", "", "C", "A")
N.CX.CY.A --> ("N", "CX", "CY", "A")
```

I tried a few combinations of greedy/non-greedy groups, but got nothing. IMHO you need to improve your specs for this to be even possible to solve at all...

Comment: Thank you. I was able to adapt your answer to get the regex that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

let's see what can be done for the combination of your example and english explanation:

```
^(N)(?:\.([B-Z][A-Z.]*?))?\.(A)(?:\.([A-Z.]+))?$
```

---

but if i was doing it in python:

```
temp = m.split('.A')
if len(temp) == 2:
    g2 = temp[0][2:]
    g4 = temp[1][1:]
else:
    g2, g4 = '', ''
groups = ("N", g2, "A", g4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
(N)\.(?:(C(?:X\.CY)?)\.)?(A)(?:\.(S))?
```

Comment: @deathApril, that's right, I thought I had that non capturing group there from some reason, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I liked this one :-)

I Think this one should do the trick:

```
(N)\.(C|CX\.CY]?)?\.?(A)?\.?(S)?
```

Comment: `A` sould be always in the 3rd group

Comment: @deathApril I have updated it so A only wil be in the third group

Comment: the 3rd group should always be `A` (not `S`)

Answer (score 0):

This Python code seems to work for the examples you've given.

```
import re
import sys

r = re.compile("^(N)\.([A-Z.]*?)\.?(A)\.?([A-Z]*)$")
m = r.search(sys.argv[1])
print m.group(1)
print m.group(2)
print m.group(3)
print m.group(4)
```